# Content of the button doesn't display after implementing control template

Tags: wpf

As I've a resource style control template for Button, In addition I've defined a control template in button itself.But the content of the Button didnot displaying. How can I resolve this ?

```
<Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <!--Set to true to not get any properties from the themes.-->
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow"/>
                <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                        <Grid>
                                <Border TextBlock.Foreground="{TemplateBinding Foreground}"
                x:Name="Border"
                CornerRadius="10"
                BorderThickness="1"/>
                                    <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
                        </Grid>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <Button Name="test" Width="50" Height="60" Content="myvalue">
            <Button.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <Ellipse Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
                        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"/>                       
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Button.Template>
        </Button>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set `TargetType` in `ControlTemplate` to `Button`.

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
    <Grid>
        <Ellipse Fill="{TemplateBinding Background}"/>
        <ContentPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                             VerticalAlignment="Center"/>                       
    </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Explanation (source [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.controltemplate.targettype.aspx)):

> If you have a standalone ControlTemplate in the resources section with
>   the TargetType property set to a type, the ControlTemplate does not
>   get applied to that type automatically. Instead, you need to specify
>   an x:Key and apply the template explicitly.
>
> Also note that the TargetType property is required on a
>   ControlTemplate if the template definition contains a
>   ContentPresenter.

Comment: Yes. I can able to view the content. Thank You. Please explain me why it's not taken target type automatically and needs to mention specifically as "Button"?

Comment: @RameshMuthiah I added explanation into my answer.

Comment: Greate findings. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. helped me.